# Laravel Eloquent "with" / "load" return null

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I am trying to get ralation (product owner) using `with` method but it returns me `null`.

After some tests i see my relation is ok if im using simple way to get it (`$goodRelation` in example), but if im trying to get relation with `with` method it any way returns `null`

```
EXAMPLES
$goodWith = Good::where('id', '4d7d36f2-75ad-4a9f-a5a5-ba8b56840414')->with('user')->first()->user;
$goodsLoad = Good::where('id', '4d7d36f2-75ad-4a9f-a5a5-ba8b56840414')->first()->load('user')->user;
$goodFirstUserFirst = Good::where('id', '4d7d36f2-75ad-4a9f-a5a5-ba8b56840414')->first()->user()->first();
$goodsRelation = Good::where('id', '4d7d36f2-75ad-4a9f-a5a5-ba8b56840414')->first()->user;

dd($goodWith, $goodsLoad, $goodFirstUserFirst, $goodsRelation);
```

Result:

```
$goodWith           -> NULL
$goodsLoad          -> NULL
$goodFirstUserFirst -> USER MODEL
$goodsRelation      -> USER MODEL
```

My `User` model:

```
public function goods()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Good::class);
}
```

My `Good` model:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

Problem in real example:
[image: Output]

[image: View file]

Why i can not get relation with `with` of `load` method ?

Comment: Can you confirm `dd(Good::where('id', '4d7d36f2-75ad-4a9f-a5a5-ba8b56840414')->with('user')->first())` dumps the _good_?  At first sight your code seems valid.  I just tested it myself with a belongsTo relationship, and that works here...

Comment: Also there is no use in adding the with or load call in this example.  Your where condition will always return just one since you're selecting on the unique id, so no need to add the with/load here to solve an N+1 which won't be here in this case anyway ;-)

Comment: @DavidHeremans, thx for answer. here just example, i want get all goods with user in relation. Yes, it ```dd(Good::where('id', '4d7d36f2-75ad-4a9f-a5a5-ba8b56840414')->with('user')->first())``` returns me good

Comment: @DavidHeremans i tried just get all goods and in view take a user relation, but in this way i have a lot of sql requests, so in that way with ```with``` it takes only 2 sql requests

Comment: Yes, if you fetch a collection of goods, and you need the user for all of them, you need to fetch the relations early to avoid the N+1 issue; just in this example when you only need one mode, it provides no benefit.  But back to your issue.  So if you do `$good = Good::where('id', '4d7d36f2-75ad-4a9f-a5a5-ba8b56840414')->with('user')->first();`  and then `dd($good->user)`, you say you are not getting the user?

Comment: @DavidHeremans in real situation i do 
Good::latest()->with('user')->get()
 and in view looping with foreach and getting user login 
$good->user->login
. for 99% of all goods i can get a user, but sometimes i can not get it (returns me null), but after testing that good with 
Good::where('id', '4d7d36f2-75ad-4a9f-a5a5-ba8b56840414')->first()->user
 - i see that i get user...

Comment: why would you do `Good::latest()->with('user')->get()` in real life?  There is no benefit from early loading the relationship when you only need one item.  Are you sure that your 'sometimes' isn't just somehere in the process when the user hasn't been attached to the good yet.  How do you create your goods?

Comment: @DavidHeremans I updated the screenshot for a better understanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**: If you are using `uuid` or `not default integer` - you should set `$keyType` in your model.

```
class Flight extends Model
{
    /**
     * The "type" of the auto-incrementing ID.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $keyType = 'string';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the Laravel 7 docs;

> If your primary key is not an integer, you should set the protected $keyType property on your model to string:

```php
<?php

class Flight extends Model
{
    /**
     * The "type" of the auto-incrementing ID.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $keyType = 'string';
}
```